# Cloud Firestore security, understanding a basic setup

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I'm trying to get my head around Cloud Firestore security and how that would work in my case. From reading the documentation, I see that client libraries are secured using Firestore rules, and server libraries are secured using IAM.

What I'm looking to achieve is quite simple. I want anyone using my iOS app to be able to read my database (and only those people). I don't really want them to have to login with username and password or OAuth unless this is essential. I'm not totally clear on whether there's a need for anonymous authentication in this case.

I want only internal admin users to be able to write to the database, e.g. through some app (native or web) I will later build.

What security setup is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

If you want everyone coming through a mobile app to be able to read everything in your database unconditionally, this is the only rule you need:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The admin SDK and all other server SDKs always bypass security rules completely, so you don't need to do anything special there.  The service account that you use just needs to have editor access to the project.

Comment: Ok thank you. Does this mean that only mobile app users have read access? Read access won't be possible through (for example) the REST API?

Comment: The REST API works exactly like the mobile SDKs in terms of authentication.  You can think of it as yet another way for the world to access your data without being a privileged service account.  If this sounds like a security hole to you, think about the fact that it's quite possible for someone to tear down your app, get your app's config, and use that to build a new app that does whatever it wants to your Firestore with the same config.

Comment: Ok I appreciate you explaining